# before_action not working when inheriting class from two level deep in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I've got a class

```
  class Superadmin::DocumentManagerController < Admin::DocumentManagerController

  end
```

This class got a parent `Admin::DocumentManagerController` which is already complete with everything (index method, etc.)

```
  class Admin::DocumentManagerController < ApplicationController

    # Some stuff

  end
```

Which itself got a parent `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_action :message_center_initialization
    # Some other stuff ...

end
```

The `ApplicationController` class itself is called correctly when i go to `/superadmin/document_manager/` ; I tried it out with a `binding.pry`.

My problem is the `message_center_initialization` method is avoided, it was supposed to be a `before_action` method that initialize a lot of important variables ...

Does anyone has an idea what's going here ? What is the `before_action` not working when we organize the classes this way ?

Comment: which version of rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out after a few hours that the `before_action` wasn't called because there were another `before_action` cutting the process in the middle, nobody could have guessed from the details I gave.

Thank you for your implication anyway, and to anyone with something similar : **be careful on what is around, before, after your `before_action` within the process ;)**

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both an `ApplicationController` and `Admin::ApplicationController`? If so, are you sure you're inheriting from the correct one?

Comment: i've only one `ApplicationController` and the `binding.pry` within the class shows it's processed :(

Comment: is it an answer or a question?